# setResult is ignored when user presses the back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

In my application, I defined 2 activities in the Manifest file like this:

```
<activity android:name=".event.EventDetailsActivity"
      android:launchMode="singleTop"
      android:parentActivityName=".main.MainActivity"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WithActionBar"/>

<activity
      android:name=".main.MainActivity"
      android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

In the `MainActivity`, I have 4 fragments. In one fragment, I start the `EventDetailsActivity` in one fragment using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(getContext(), EventDetailsActivity.class));
intent.putExtra(EventDetailsActivity.ID_KEY, id);
intent.putExtra(EventDetailsActivity.TYPE_KEY, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, DETAILS_REQUEST);
```

How I handle the back navigation in `EventDetailsActivity`:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Navigate up");
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Back pressed " + isChanged);
    if (isChanged) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Set result");
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

The problem is `onActivityResult` get called in the calling `Fragment` but the result code is always `0 (RESULT_CANCELED)`. Also, `onSupportNavigateUp` never gets called if I press the back arrow button. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Get rid of `finish();` after `setResult();`

Comment: when you go back to the previous activity, is `isChanged` equals to true? If it is not, the problem might be there.

Comment: even if isChanged is true, it is still RESULT_CANCELED. Remove finish() doesn't help,

Answer (score 1):

Remove : `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

and remove `super.onBackpressed` in on onBackpressed function 
because you used finish()

Answer (score 0):

As you're getting the `onActivityResult` callback from your `Fragment` correctly I assume the problem is about setting the proper result to the starting `Activity`. So here's I'm proposing some edit you might consider in your code.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// No longer necessary
/* @Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Navigate up");
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
} */

/* @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Super call needs to be the first line 
    super.onBackPressed();

    if (isChanged) {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
    }
} */
```

So I've omitted the `onBackPressed` function because by default, if the user presses the back button, the result will be `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`.

So there's a hacky solution here is to implement the key event callback listener like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
         setResult(RESULT_OK);
         finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Hope that helps!